# How to add and remove a link from link list in OrientDB using OrientJS APIs

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

In my Orient database I have created two classes `main` & `sub`. Properties of those classes are as follows.

Main

- name (string)
- description (string)
- child (link list)

Sub

- name (string)
- description (string)

I'm using a node application to update data on this database. What I'm trying to do is add a record to class `Sub` and add it's `@rid` to `Main`'s `child` link list of a existing record. For the insertion, I use below code.

```
database
  .insert().into('Sub')
  .set(values)
  .one()
  .then(function (data) {})
```

But I'm struggling with adding `data['@rid']` to `Main`'s `child` link list using OrientJS API. I tried

```
database
  .insert().into('Sub')
  .set(values)
  .one()
  .then(function (data) {
      database.update('Main')
      .set({child:data['@rid']})
      .where('#01:0')
      .one();
  });
```

But that did't work. If i use query to add this link, it's looks like below,

```
update #01:0 add children = #02:0
```

How can i add a link to a link list using  OrientJS without using an query

```
db.query('update #01:0 add children = #02:0');
```

Comment: What's wrong with using query? You can also try this one: ```CREATE LINK <link> TYPE [<link-type>] FROM <source-class>.<source-property> TO <destination-class>.<destination-property> ```

Answer (score 0):

The add is not documented yet but you can see some example here

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/blob/6102052e903edc4721f490e08899cbc9672df9be/test/db/statement-test.js#L511